# Package Manager is missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2018.3.0f2.

I have installed everything described [here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/packages-compilation-failures-on-new-project-because-of-missing-net-core-prerequisites) but still Package Manager is missing for my old project. I tried deleting the whole line `"com.unity.package-manager-ui": "2.0.3",` but still PM is missing.

When I create new fresh project PM is visible there, but this is not important for me. I need to make my old project running fine again. Can someone assist please ?

Here is my Editors.log: https://pastebin.com/5fctESFQ

Comment: Deleting the dependency in the manifest will likely not get you a PM, hehe. Have you tried [installing as described here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@2.0/manual/index.html)? I can't see any errors except from your own scripts in the log you linked, the package management seems to be working fine.